# AJAX call not hitting required MVC Route

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

- ASP.NET 4.61

  - MVC 5
  - jQuery 1.11.3
  - MVC Pager 3.0.1 (http://en.webdiyer.com/mvcpager/)

I have a report today that paging is no longer working in my application. As this is a recent update something has changed, but I am at a loss to see how to fix it.

Ultimately it comes down to the fact that the incorrect action in my controller is being called. I have two actions as follows:

**1. Non AJAX**

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult ByRegion(string aRegionNameOne, string aRegionNameTwo = "", string aRegionNameThree = "", string aRegionNameFour = "")
```

**2. AJAX Paging via MVC Pager**

```
public virtual ActionResult ByRegionForPage(string aRegionNameOne, string aRegionNameTwo = "", string aRegionNameThree = "", string aRegionNameFour = "", int p = 1)
```

When a paging link is clicked within MVC Pager I get a link looking like this via FireBug:

> https://localhost/region/australia/cruises/%232?X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest

instead of what I am seeing in the address bar which is:

> https://localhost/region/australia/cruises#p=2

My routes are:

**A. NON Paging Route (NON AJAX)**

```
aRoutes.MapRoute(RouteNames.SIDE_BAR_MENU_SEARCH_BY_REGION_1_LEVELS, "region/{aRegionNameOne}/cruises/{aPageNumber}", new
                                                                                                                                  {
                                                                                                                                      controller = MVC.Cruises.Name,
                                                                                                                                      action = MVC.Cruises.ActionNames.ByRegion,
                                                                                                                                      area = "",
                                                                                                                                      //Work around bug in T4MVC https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC/issues/28
                                                                                                                                      aPageNumber = UrlParameter.Optional
                                                                                                                                  }
                );
```

**B. Paging Route (AJAX)**

```
aRoutes.MapRoute(RouteNames.SIDE_BAR_MENU_SEARCH_BY_REGION_1_LEVELS_FOR_PAGE, "region/{aRegionNameOne}/cruises/#{p}", new
                                                                                                                                 {
                                                                                                                                  controller = MVC.Cruises.Name,
                                                                                                                                  action = MVC.Cruises.ActionNames.ByRegionForPage,
                                                                                                                                  area = "",
                                                                                                                                  //Work around bug in T4MVC https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC/issues/28
                                                                                                                                  p = UrlParameter.Optional
                                                                                                                              }
```

So it is clear that **%232?X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest** is causing me to hit route A and hence action 1 instead of the intended route B.

By the looks of things MVCPager is mangling the URL as the HTML is:

```
<a data-pageindex="2" href="/region/australia/cruises/%232">2</a>
```

Has anyone got any ideas on a fix or seen this behaviour?

Comment: You can have one action only and make the page number nullable, check its value and if it is null then ignore it and otherwise return the data by the provided page number

Comment: I managed to solve my issue by simplifying my routing.